# Debugging electron application VS Code 2021

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron

I am trying to debug the Electron application from VS CODE but now I am having problems.

I am able to debug only the main.js file and I want to be able to debug the rest of the .js files as well.

LAUNCH.JSON

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Electron Main",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
        "type": "pwa-node"
    }
    ]
}
```

[Files loaded and files missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFRax.png)

Comment: You might be able to use the browser dev tools. [read this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/debugging-main-process), that suggests that debugging the main.js file is the HARD bit, and that's the bit you already figured out. `The DevTools in an Electron browser window can only debug JavaScript that's executed in that window (i.e. the web pages).` -- check [this link](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension) out for devtools

Comment: I know for browser dev tools, but I want to avoid that.  So the problem is how to preload some js files which will be debugged later.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any documentation on how to make that possible